# A word that means "worsen", but implies greater magnitude

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing about mental health counselling and how centres are often fully booked. I then say: "I'm sure many others have the same story, and crises that deserve immediate attention are left to -- "

What's the word I'm looking for? It's like exacerbate, but reflexive. The problem is being exacerbated, but I don't want to use passive voice. Most words in English that are synonymous with "worsen" imply getting weaker or smaller, but I want to say that the crisis grows stronger (yet worse at the same time).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Requests for single-word definitions are off-topic for us but acceptable on English SE if properly formatted. I've asked the mods to migrate your question there.

Comment: Fester (become worse or more intense, especially through long-term neglect or indifference) is used in similar circumstances, but might not be appropriate depending on the context since its strongly associated with infections.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for is deteriorated

Comment: However, I fear you suffer the narrow view of most novelists obsessed with language.

Comment: *you suffer the narrow view of most novelists obsessed with language* sounds opinionated and bordering rude. Care to explain to the poor obsessed novelist what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> **atrophy** - a wasting away or progressive decline
>
> **degenerate** - having sunk to a condition below that which is normal to a type

Both taken from merriam-webster.com

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could refer to the effect of the crisis with the deterioration "plummeting, crashing,

the crisis plummets ...  our counselling system into ...
the crisis crashes ... against a strained capacity to respond to a skyrocketing client base / work load.

Comment: Hello, Mints, and welcome to English Language and Usage. If you are going to be posting here with any regularity, please take a moment to vist our help page on ["How to write a good answer"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) We are looking for answers that provide sources to support explanations, as well as context and links.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the word you need is ***magnify***, isn't it? - "...problems are left to *magnify*".

Comment: Mental health counselling [and how] centres are often fully booked.  I don't know the statistics on how often immediate attention is important in outcomes.  In some situations it could well be crucial, in counteracting an overdose or alleviating a epileptic seizure. Whether a time to cool down before being offered or asking for treatment is essential is another matter.  A facility ought to try to triage--rank the importance of immediate care given its resources.  Some problems may magnify; for others time may begin to alleviate the worse.

Comment: "*...problems are left to resolve themselves* "?

Comment: Surely I didn't say that.